# ¿Cómo puedo conectarme a un servidor FTP mediante Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, ftp

intento conectarme a un servidor en hostinger mediante Android Studio y no puedo, logro conectarme mediante Filezilla y el MsDOS de Windows, pero mediante la clase .net de Apache Commons me dá un error, y es que la función propia de esta libreria "connect(host)" me retorna un valor nulo.

```
try {
        FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
        ftp.connect(host);

    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("//ERROR://"+ e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: ¿Hay algún motivo que justifique quererte conectar vía FTP? Por ejemplo, si es para obtener datos que están en ese servidor, lo que se suele hacer hoy día es exponer esa información mediante una API o un Servicio Web. Así accederías a la información del servidor de una forma sencilla, segura y ligera.

Comment: @A.Cedano, sí. es para guardar información en la nube, el lio de usar las API que se encuentran en internét es por las licencias(ya que ninguna es CCO), la libreria de APACHE Commos .net posee la implementación y los métodos necesarios; pero no funciona en Android Studio (o almenos a mí no me ha funcionado).

Comment: Me parece que te estás complicando demasiado. Tú mismo puedes programar una API. No es tan complicado como parece y, si quieres tener una App moderna, y ofrecerla a miles o millones de usuarios, tendrás que hacerlo sí o sí (o usar almacenamiento en la nube como Firebase, pero ese es otro tema). La API serían direcciones a un servidor web (un dominio tuyo propio por ejemplo) donde programas código PHP que se conecta a la BD, extrae los datos que se pidan desde la Aplicación y los devuelve en forma de JSON (u otro) para que la Aplicación consuma esos datos (los muestre o haga lo que sea).

Comment: Es así como funcionan las Apps hoy día, más o menos. Pensar en FTP para servir tus datos me parece totalmente fuera de lugar, a no ser que sea un tipo de aplicación muy particular que justifique este tipo de conexiones (como una App de aprendizaje de código donde se necesite hacer prácticas en conexiones FTP o cosas parecidas). En cuanto a conectar tu App con los datos, existen librerias como Volley que facilitan el trabajo y si usas Firebase, Android tiene sus propias librerías, bastante fáciles e intuitivas para conectarte.

Comment: jejjejje, lo tendré en cuenta, muchas gracias por los comentarios compañero ! :D